# Android beacon location

Tags: android, location, beacon

I'm using Estimote location beacons and Android Studio in order to implement an indoor system

I did this code:

```
package com.example.hamat.name;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.estimote.indoorsdk.IndoorLocationManagerBuilder;
import com.estimote.indoorsdk_module.algorithm.OnPositionUpdateListener;
import com.estimote.indoorsdk_module.cloud.CloudCallback;
import com.estimote.indoorsdk_module.cloud.EstimoteCloudException;
import com.estimote.indoorsdk_module.cloud.IndoorCloudManager;
import com.estimote.indoorsdk_module.cloud.IndoorCloudManagerFactory;
import com.estimote.indoorsdk_module.cloud.LocationPosition;
import com.estimote.cloud_plugin.common.EstimoteCloudCredentials;
import com.estimote.indoorsdk_module.view.IndoorLocationView;
import com.estimote.internal_plugins_api.cloud.CloudCredentials;
import com.estimote.indoorsdk_module.algorithm.ScanningIndoorLocationManager;

public class MyLocation extends AppCompatActivity {
    IndoorLocationView indoorLocationView = (IndoorLocationView) findViewById(R.id.indoor_view);
    Location location;
    ScanningIndoorLocationManager indoorLocationManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_location);

        // Connection to Estimote and the App
        CloudCredentials cloudCredentials = new EstimoteCloudCredentials("ID ", "Token");
        IndoorCloudManager cloudManager = new IndoorCloudManagerFactory().create(this, cloudCredentials);

        // Get the saved map  in estimote
        cloudManager.getLocation("XXXXX The Map ID XXXXX", new CloudCallback<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void failure(EstimoteCloudException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void success(Location location) {
                // view the map in the app ( have to insert it first in the Layout=========================
                indoorLocationView = (IndoorLocationView) findViewById(R.id.indoor_view);
                indoorLocationView.setLocation(location);

                // scan beacons automatically==============================================================
                indoorLocationManager = new IndoorLocationManagerBuilder(MyLocation.this, location)
                        .withDefaultScanner()
                        .build();



            }
        });
}
```

In location variable, I get this error message

```
      setLocation(com.estimote.indoorsdk_module.cloud.Location) in
 IndoorLocationView cannot be applied to (android.location.Location)
```

What should I do?
do you think I did some mistake in importing the packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing the wrong type of Location. In the imports at the beginning of your class, import com.estimote.indoorsdk_module.cloud.Location instead of android.location.Location. Remember to instantiate your variable before using it

Comment: Thank you! it works!
One more thing, I did a mistake in one line, too. I replace this

`indoorLocationManager = new IndoorLocationManagerBuilder(MyLocation.this, location)`

with this

`indoorLocationManager = new IndoorLocationManagerBuilder(MyLocation.this, location,cloudCredentials)`